# can I recover any data from a device and send it to the ibm watson iot platform cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, ibm-watson, gateway

Good morning everyone,

I am currently working on a project which I use **IBM Watson IoT Platform** which will be linked with a Gateway,

Can I retrieve any parameter from the Gateway (ex: SSID, Password ...) and send it to the IBM Watson IoT Platform or I can only send an event triggered by the Gateway

**Knowing that I use the MQTT protocol to send events to the IBM Watson IoT Platform**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command messages can be sent to gateways through the platform using MQTT to e.g. tell the gateway what data to send.
Code would have to be running on the gateway that listened for these commands and returned the information requested in the form of events (MQTT messages).